# curl SSL certificate issue - Go Daddy secure certificate authority - g2

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I need to connect to a 3rd party API signed by **Go Daddy secure certificate authority - G2**. (I verified that in the Chrome browser).

When I try to issue a curl request to that API over port 8443 (which is opened) I receive the following error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
> Closing connection 0 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More details here:
> https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I checked and in the default curl cacert store there is **Go Daddy secure certificate authority - G2** listed.
I also downloaded the latest cacert store from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and used that by supplying --cacert option to curl command and again I received the same error.

By using -v option with curl command in output I receive which cacert store is used so with that I am sure it is using the one I explicitly added to the command.

Since the certificate exists in cacert store that I am telling curl to use, what else am I missing here?

Comment: GoDaddy G2 is a root and does not directly sign any server cert(s); there is at least one intermediate CA and its (or their) cert(s), commonly called **intermediate or 'chain' cert(s)**, must be provided by the server in the handshake. Is it or are they? Browsers like Chrome can often work-around missing chain cert(s) using the AIA extension, but curl, at least curl using OpenSSL library like yours does, cannot. If you have openssl, try `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -servername $host` to see what chain is sent (or not); in 1.1.1 up can omit -servername.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are right. Thanks a lot. It appears that GoDaddy Secure Server Certificate (Intermediate Certificate) - G2 was used.